# Can require() be used to revert low level call() that were made before it?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, eth-call, revert

**CODE:**

```
(success, ) = contract.call(); // low level call
if (success) {
    // do something
}

// instead of below check, can I just use require(condition)?
if (!condition) {
    revert();
}
```

Instead of checking the condition and using `revert()`, can I use `require(condition)` to ensure the whole tx including the low level calls are reverted?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can

require() uses the 0xfd opcode to generate an error condition. That is, in the end it calls revert()
So the difference is immaterial between the constructs:

```
if (!condition) {
    revert();
}
```

и

```
require(condition);
```